# importing from same folder, after being called by jupyter in outside folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, python-import

I am not able to import files in a module from other modules in the same package, when called outside the package, in a jupyter notebook.

I have a project of the following structure in a folder called project:

```
├───data
│   ├───external
│   ├───interim
│   ├───processed
│   └───raw
├───docs
├───models
├───notebooks
│   ├───data_loading.ipynb
│   └───wandb
├───references
├───reports
│   └───figures
├───src
│   ├───data
│   │   │───datasets.py
│   │   │───data_util.py
│   │   └───__init__.py
│   ├───features
│   ├───__init__.py
│   ├───models
│   ├───visualization
│   └───__pycache__
└───wandb
```

From the jupyter notebook `data_loading.ipynb` in the notebooks folder, I am attempting the following:

```
import os
import sys
module_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join('..'))
if module_path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(module_path)

from src.data.datasets import TransformersFromRaw
```

It gives me the error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'data_util'
```

Which stems from an attempt to import functions from a module in the same folder as datasets.py

```
from data_util import check_cuda_available, tokenize_preserve_labels, substitute_navn
```

I have tried to set the current directory to the project folder, but it still does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try importing like this -

```
from .data_util import check_cuda_available, tokenize_preserve_labels, substitute_navn
```

In python3 you have to use `.` operator to specify the current directory while importing any module.